# trying to find max value in a field and define value as variable

Tags: arcpy

I am new to scripting. I have been searching around on here and other sites, and can't seem to find something quite like what I need.

I am trying to find a max value within a field, and store that max value as a variable to get used for other processes later. I think I am defining the variable incorrectly, but I can't seem to find anything on how to define the max value of a field as a variable.

Here is what I have so far.

In this code, centerline is a variable that grabs a user defined feature class (this code is being set up as an Arc tool). SAMPINS is the name of the field that I am trying to grab the max value for. I realize that I can use statistics to get the max value (and maybe that is a better option here...), as well, but I still do not know how to define this as a variable.

The traceback error is telling me that addfields is not defined on line 179. Line 179 is the line that reads "addfields - 1 < [SAMPINS]".

```
addfields = 0
fieldtag = str(addfields)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(centerline, "SAMPINS") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        value = row[0]
        if value > addfields:
            addfields = value

while (addfields > 1):
    arcpy.AddField_management(centerline, "F_"+fieldtag, "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    if addfields:
        addfeilds - 1 < [SAMPINS]
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(centerline, "F_"+fieldtag, "[SAMPINS] + [SAMPDIST] + [SAMPLF]", "VB", "")
    else:
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(centerline, "F_"+fieldtag, "0", "VB", "") 
    addfields = addfields - 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code seems pretty close:

```
max_value = -99999999
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(centerline, "SAMPINS") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        max_value = max(int(row[0]), max_value)
# do something with max_value
```

Note: using GeoSharp's idea below of using:

```
max_value = float('-inf')
```

is the most bulletproof way of dealing with negative data values

Comment: No need to initialize a value at all:  `max_value = max(value for value, in cursor)`

Comment: Slick, but maybe not the best advice for someone "new to scripting".

Answer (score 1):

With this code snippet, once the loop is completed the variable `max_value` will contain the maximum value of the column in question:

```
max_value = float('-inf')
input_feature_class = r'C:\path\to\feature_class'
field_to_get_max_value_for = "SAMPINS"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_feature_class , field_to_get_max_value_for) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        value = row[0]
        if value > max_value:
            max_value = value
```

It is best to start by using the absolute minimum value of a `float` in Python to start with, e.g. `float('-inf')`. You are essentially guaranteed to have the first value in search cursor loop to be greater than it. From there if a value is ever greater than the first value in the column it will replace the value for `max_value` and continually do this until the loop is complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot GeoSharp! This seemed to helped get past that initial road block, but it seems that the max_value variable does not continue through? Maybe the while loop needs to be situated underneath the max value grab?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are looking for the max value in a field called "SAMPINS"...

Therefore the way ive done this before is to use a list, append all the values of SAMPINS to the list, then find the max value for it.

Therefore try this:

```
list = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(centerline, "SAMPINS") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        list.append(row[0])
max_value = max(list)
```